# onclick events in jquery on AJAX loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having trouble using the ".on" method in jQuery on content that has been inserted via AJAX. I currently use ".live", however this is deprecated and ".on" is what I'm after.

My working code is:

```
$('.folderadmin').live("click", function() 
{   
   // Do stuff
})
```

When I replace the .live with .on, it fails to work. I believe it is because the element .folderadmin is loaded via AJAX - thus why we needed to use .live to access it. How can I access the DOM and recognize .folderadmin with .on?

Comment: Have a quick look at the API documentation for `on` and you´ll notice that it takes more args. than `live` did/does. http://api.jquery.com/on/ `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )` vs. `.live( events, handler(eventObject) )`.

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: 1.7.2 - Also, I'm using the same technique as shown in the first example and it simply doesn't work; I think it's because the content is ajaxed. Not sure.

Comment: what error is printed on the console , check it out using firebug or google chrome console

Comment: also if you post your code we can help you more with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.folderadmin').live("click", function() {   
   // Do stuff
});
```

is same as

```
$(document).on("click", '.folderadmin', function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

But it is not necessary to bind to `document`, you could bind to the parents container of `.folderadmin` which has already exists in the dom tree.

```
$('#the_parent_id').on("click", '.folderadmin', function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your jQuery version since .on was added on jQuery version 1.7 where the .live() method is apparently deprecated 
[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

 it should be like :

```
$(".folderadmin").on("click", function(){
  //enter code here
});
```

Comment: Just a quick note, I have been using 1.7.2 since it was released and live() does work for me with no problems.

Comment: Deprecated but available and working. Oh well, problem solved.